# How to define the HTML file extension in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, asp.net-core

My project does not recognize the css and other files in the html files I have created, although I have written the extension paths correctly. How can I fix?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to configure [serving static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in **Startup**

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); //serves wwwroot by default
```

To serve your `theme` folder you need to add the following lines

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "theme")),
    RequestPath = "/theme"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not put the correct path there. Your "style.css" is in 'theme/src/style.css' not in the 'theme/style.css'. Also use VS Code not Visual Studio because is useless if you create just files.
Also you did not provide all the files that are in the JS folder and CSS folder.

Comment: The src folder is not open. I typed the extension of "style.css" file correctly. But somehow Visual Studio does not recognize the files. I would like to use vs code, but if I define database and all functions in Visual Studio, defining the same ones over vscode will take me a lot of time.